# Плавное увеличение/уменьшение числа на JQuery

Tags: jquery, animate

Использую следующий код:

```js
let n = $('#test').text();

$({numberValue: n}).animate({numberValue: 5000}, {
   duration: 500,
   easing: "linear",
   step: function(val) {
      $('#test').text(Math.round(val));
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test">500</div>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать плавное увеличение/уменьшение числа, используя `animate`, но с автоматическим разделением разрядов при анимации, с возможностью задать свой разделитель.

То есть, чтобы выглядело так:

```
1000 => 1 000; 1001 => 1 001; и т.д.
```

Пытался передавать в `animate` сразу числа с разделением, но не работает:(

Нашёл плагин для анимации чисел - [jquery.animateNumber](https://github.com/aishek/jquery-animateNumber), но хочется без плагинов.

**Уточнение:** в блоке с `id="test"` будут числа уже с разделением, т.е. 1 000 и т.д. Отсчёт должен начинаться каждый раз с числа, которое находится в блоке, а не с 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let n = $('#test').text().replace(/\D/g,'');

function separateNumber(x) {
  return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " "); 
  //разделитель можно задать тут вторым аргументом для метода replace. Сейчас, как видно, пробел
}

$({numberValue: n}).animate({numberValue: 1200}, {
   duration: 500000,
   easing: "linear",
   step: function(val) {
      $('#test').text(separateNumber(Math.round(val)));
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test">1 000</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Добавил уточнение в вопрос, посмотрите, пожалуйста:)

Comment: вроде соответствует. Поставил начальное число - тысячу с разделителем.

Comment: Если замедлить анимацию до `duration: 5000` - видно, что отсчёт начинается с 0, а не с 1 000:)

Comment: Не могу согласиться. Замедлил анимацию в ответе

Comment: Прошу прощения, вставил к себе в код, а у меня немного не так сработало:)

Comment: Больше спасибо за Вашу помощь:)

Answer (score 2):

Форматирование toLocaleString можно настроить с помощью опций

```js
let n = $('#test').text().replace(/\s/g, '');

$({numberValue: n}).animate({numberValue: 5000}, {
   duration: 2000,
   easing: "linear",
   step: function(val) {
      $('#test').text(Math.round(val).toLocaleString());
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test">2 000</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Такой вариант использовал, но он не работает, когда в блоке с `id="test"` будет 1 000 (уже с разделением), точнее работает, но каждый раз отсчет начинается с 0, а надо с 1 000. Моя ошибка, не добавил данное уточнение в вопрос:(

Comment: Внес правки в код

Comment: В Вашем варианте отсчёт начинается с 0, если в блоке указать 1 000:) Попробуйте замедлить анимацию до `duration: 5000`

Comment: Сейчас норм должно быть

Comment: Отлично, спасибо большое за Ваш ответ и уделённое время) Только в регулярное выражение добавьте `g`, т.е.`/\s/g`, чтобы от 1 000 000 тоже корректно работал код:)

Comment: Думаю будет честно, если отмечу ответ от автора @zhurof, т.к. в его ответе имеется возможность задать свой разделитель:) Конечно, с помощью `toLocaleString()` тоже можно настроить разделитель, но не так гибко, как с отдельной функцией `separateNumber`. Всего Вам доброго:)